# Difference between two dataframe and output a specific column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes ( df1 & df2)  with same headings.

Both dataframes contains same number of rows.

There are around 20 columns in each dataframes.

The dataframes differs for some columns (any one or more out of 20 columns)

There is a particular column (ssno) which is unique for both.

I need to generate the output(ssno) for those rows which differes in any of the 20 field'.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First compare both `DataFrame`s and get al least one `True`s per rows by [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and then use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering `ssno` column:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ssno':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[70,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,90,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaXbbb')})

print (df1)
   B   C  D   E  F ssno
0  4  70  1   5  a    a
1  5   8  3   3  a    b
2  4   9  5   6  X    c
3  5   4  7  90  b    d
4  5   2  1   2  b    e
5  4   3  0   4  b    f

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ssno':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df2)
   B  C  D  E  F ssno
0  4  7  1  5  a    a
1  5  8  3  3  a    b
2  4  9  5  6  a    c
3  5  4  7  9  b    d
4  5  2  1  2  b    e
```

---

```
s = df1.loc[(df1 != df2).any(1), 'ssno']
print (s)
0    a
2    c
3    d
Name: ssno, dtype: object
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df1 != df2)
       B      C      D      E      F   ssno
0  False   True  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False   True  False
3  False  False  False   True  False  False
4  False  False  False  False  False  False
5  False  False  False  False  False  False

print ((df1 != df2).any(1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you @Jezrael. It helped me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Is it also possible to get the column name for index (0, 2, 3) which differs? Like for index 0, it differs at [a, d, e] etc

Comment: I think yes, do you need `s2 = df1.columns[(df1 != df2).any()]` ?

Comment: Or maybe `s2 = df1[(df1 != df2)].stack().rename_axis(('idx','cols')).reset_index(name='val_df1')` ?

Comment: Thanks Jezrael, your 2nd solution worked. I was looking for this only. Great. Thanks and regards.